# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints, where is it coming from?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have this warning when building my app. I'm using a storyboard, but all constraints are proper over there.. I don't know where else I have to look..

```
2014-04-29 14:18:54.072 gTicket[1540:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16593a90 V:[UIView:0x165a1dd0(429)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x165b3c50 V:[UILabel:0x165b3d80(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x165b37c0 V:[UIView:0x165945a0(52)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x165ac960 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x165a8670]-(36)-[UIView:0x165a1dd0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x165a9060 V:[UIView:0x165a1dd0]-(14)-[UILabel:0x165b3d80]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x165b50d0 V:[UILabel:0x165b3d80]-(16)-[UIView:0x165945a0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x165a1e80 V:[UIView:0x165945a0]-(1)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x165adfc0]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x165adf00 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x165a8670(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x165ae3b0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x165a8670]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x165a6940 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1659c120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x165adfc0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x165a12d0 _UILayoutGuide:0x165adfc0.bottom == UIView:0x165a6940.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x165baf00 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x165a6940(431)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16593a90 V:[UIView:0x165a1dd0(429)]>
```

Is it possible to determine which UILabel and which view it is complaining about?

Comment: Didn't you forget to  [eachView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]?

Comment: ohh gee, yes, it's a new view i've made. So yes, i forgot this. thanks!